# How can I get the style of selected cells?

Tags: front-end, cells

How can I get the style such as Input, Text, Code, etc., of a selected cell? If a group of cells is selected, how can I get styles of all the cells in the group?

Comment: Programmatically? If it's just one cell, then a manual method: you can right-click on the cell's bracket, mouse over to "Style", and then see what's ticked...

Comment: @J.M. yes programmatically. I wasn't precise.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
"Style" /. Developer`CellInformation[nb]
```

where `nb` is the `NotebookObject` for the notebook you care about.  Since you could have multiple cells selected, this will always return a list.  It's also possible to have no cells selected, in which case `CellInformation` will return `$Failed` and the above code would throw an error.

Comment: God, it's even in the help and I couldn't find it.. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @John Fultz .  I used your answer in formulating a routine to answer "Is there a shortcut to select all cells above the current cursor position?", picking out just the "Input" style cells to evaluate (which is what the asker was trying to do).

Comment: Can I use this within one notebook. I have yet to manage to get anything different from `$Failed` out of `Developer\`CellInformation[nb]`. Perhaps because the selection changes when I hit shift enter to run the code. (I used `nb = InputNotebook[]` to set nb to the current notebook.)

Comment: @Kvothe ``Developer`CellInformation`` also works on `CellObject`, allowing you to get information on cells regardless of whether they're selected.  You can use various invocations of `Cells[]` to acquire the desired list of `CellObject`s.