# How to programmatically clear the contents of a set of selected, non-contiguous notebook cells?

Tags: front-end, cells

I'm writing some code that programmatically modifies the contents of the notebook it's running in. My code uses `NotebookLocate` to select all the cells in the notebook that have a particular tag — in my case, they happen to be several non-adjacent Input cells (but not necessarily all input cells in the notebook). Now, I want to clear the **contents** of those cells, but not delete the cells themselves.

This seems to me like something that ought to be fairly easy, but I'm having a dickens of a time figuring out a way. I know I can get a list of `CellObject` expressions for the selected cells by calling `SelectedCells`, but is there some way to write a function I could map onto that list, which takes a `CellObject` and erases its contents? Or… Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated to address `BoxData` issue**

An alternative to using `NotebookDelete` is to use `NotebookWrite`/`NotebookRead`. Here is a function that clears the contents of a cell:

```
eraseCellContents[cell_] := NotebookWrite[
    cell,
    Replace[NotebookRead[cell], Cell[h_, r___] :> Cell[emptyCell[h], r]]
]

emptyCell[_BoxData] := BoxData[""]
emptyCell[_] := ""
```

The helper function `emptyCell` makes sure that cells which use 2D typesetting (e.g., `StandardForm`) retain their 2D typesetting capabilities.

Example usage:

```
NotebookLocate["FOO"]
eraseCellContents /@ SelectedCells[]
```

Comment: Wow. I wouldn't have thought of doing something so cryptic -- I guess I'm not yet fluent enough with patterns, delayed rules, and the like.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming they are all `"Input"` cells you can do:

```
Scan[
   (SelectionMove[#, All, CellContents]; NotebookDelete[]) &
 , SelectedCells[(*notebook*)]
]
```

instead of `NotebookDelete` you can use `FrontEndTokenExecute["Clear"]`

The assumption about input cell is important because otherwise `DefaultDuplicateCellStyle` will replace the modified cell's style. [(1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/78438/5478)

So in general you may want to use this:

```
Scan[
    ( SelectionMove[#, All, CellContents]
    ; Internal`WithLocalSettings[
          CurrentValue[#, DefaultDuplicateCellStyle
          ] = Lookup[Developer`CellInformation[#], "Style", "Input"] (*(2)*)
        , NotebookDelete[]
        , CurrentValue[#, DefaultDuplicateCellStyle] = Inherited
      ]
     ) &
   , SelectedCells[]
]
```

One could argue that it may erase explicit `DefaultDuplicateCellStyle` set for Cell, but this option is usually set at notebook's level.

(2) [How can I get the style of selected cells?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21915/5478)

Comment: Might also be worth mentioning the issue if `Editable->False` is set

Comment: @b3m2a1 worth a comment for sure, not sure if more attention is required ;) should be obvious.

Comment: Aah. I had been afraid of `NotebookDelete` because I thought it would always delete the entire cell.

Comment: @ibeatty I see, don't forget `CellContents` then :)