# Preserving changed Output style

Tags: customization, stylesheet, style

Let's say I have a stylesheet with two slightly different `"Output"` and `"Output2"` styles.

`"Input"` generates `"Output"` which can be switched with `"Output2"` using <kbd>Tab</kbd>/<kbd>Backspace</kbd>.

The problem is that `"Output2"` is replaced with `"Output"` if you evaluate input again. I'd like to preserve changed style.

Unfortunately there is not much flexibility/documentation for [`GeneratedCellStyles`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=GeneratedCellStyles)

I have a solution but my approach looks ugly because one has to deal with exceptions like Input being the last cell in the notebook or protecting other styles which follow Input.

### So the question is:

Is there something I've missed in cell/notebook options? Can my code be improved in any way?

The solution needs to work from a stylesheet level.

### My approach

The fix is to use `CellProlog`/`CellEpilog` for `"Input"` style.

```
CreateDocument[
  { ExpressionCell[Defer[1 + 1], "Input"]
  , ExpressionCell[2, "Output2"]
  }
, StyleDefinitions -> Notebook[
    { Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]]
    , Cell[StyleData["Output"]
      , StyleKeyMapping -> {"Tab" -> "Output2"}]
    , Cell[StyleData["Output2", StyleDefinitions -> StyleData["Output"]  (*1*)]
      , Background -> RGBColor[1, 0, 1]
      , StyleKeyMapping -> {"Backspace" -> "Output"}
      ]
    , Cell[ (*here starts the solution*)
        StyleData["Input"]
      , CellProlog :> SetOptions[ (*2*)
          EvaluationCell[]
        , TaggingRules -> {"OutputStyle" -> Module[{nc = NextCell[], style}
          , Which[
              nc === None
            , Inherited
            , MemberQ[{"Output2"}
              , style = ("Style" /. Developer`CellInformation[nc] (*3*))
              ]
            , style
            , True
            , Inherited
            ]
          ]}]
        , CellEpilog :> Module[
            { nc = NextCell[]
            , style = CurrentValue[EvaluationCell[], {TaggingRules, "OutputStyle"}]
            }
          , Which[
              Or[nc === None, style === Inherited]
            , Null
            , True
            , SelectionMove[nc, All, Cell, AutoScroll -> False]
            ; FrontEndTokenExecute[EvaluationNotebook[], "Style", style](*4*)
            ; SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], After, Cell]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    ]
   ]
```

#### Refs

- https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=GeneratedCellStyles

1. [Is there a way to base one style on another?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14425/5478)
2. `SetOptions` because of [Notebook's TaggingRules inherit too much](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/139017/5478)
3. [How can I get the style of selected cells?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21915/5478)
4. [Set the style of a cell](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/78774/5478)

Comment: If you substitute `CellEpilog :> Module[...]` by something like (this only works for 1+1 ... ) `CellEvaluationFunction->((NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook[],Cell[BoxData@ToExpression@#,CurrentValue[EvaluationCell[], {TaggingRules, "OutputStyle"}]]])&)` it sems to not flicker.

Comment: @RolfMertig yep, so it does not work for input cells that contain no (`1+1;`) or multiple outputs (`1+1 \n 1+1`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an improvement. We can drop `CellEpilog` and set `"GeneratedCellStyles"` from `CellProlog` using old code.

```
CreateDocument[
  { ExpressionCell[Defer[1 + 1], "Input"]
  , ExpressionCell[2, "Output2"]
  }
, StyleDefinitions -> Notebook[
    { Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]]
    , Cell[StyleData["Output"]
      , StyleKeyMapping -> {"Tab" -> "Output2"}
      ]
    , Cell[StyleData["Output2", StyleDefinitions -> StyleData["Output"]  (*1*)]
      , Background -> RGBColor[1, 0, 1]
      , StyleKeyMapping -> {"Backspace" -> "Output"}
      ]
    , Cell[StyleData["Input"]
      , CellProlog :> SetOptions[
          EvaluationCell[]
        , "GeneratedCellStyles" -> {
            "Output" -> Module[{nc = NextCell[]}
            , Which[
                nc === None, Inherited
              , "Output2" === ("Style" /. Developer`CellInformation[nc]), "Output2"
              , True, Inherited
              ]
            ]
          }
        ]
      ]
     }
   ]
 ]
```

I set the option for `EvaluationCell` so that in case of `Abort` it won't affect the whole notebook.