# How to keep a DisplayFormula cell connected to its Input cell?

Tags: front-end, stylesheet, display

I am writing up some notes and enter formulas (integrals, products, PDFs, ...) in *Input* cells to get the formatted result in the *Output* cell. When I restyle the output cell as a *DisplayFormula* the cell loses its connection to the *Input* cell.  That is it does not collapse with the *Input* cell and reevaluating the *Input* cell creates a new *Output* cell instead of updating the *DisplayFormula* cell.

How can I keep the *DisplayFormula* connected to its *Input* cell?  I would like for it to behave as the *Output* cell but with the *DisplayFormula* styling.  I'm not too savvy with style sheet editing but would like a stylesheet based solution so that I can easily apply the it to new and existing notebooks.

Comment: Output2 -> DisplayFormula and it seems to be a duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/159053/5478. Do you agree?

Comment: @Kuba  That link is not working because when I change `StyleData["Output"]` to `StyleData["DisplayFormula"]` for `"Output2"` the output cell in the generated document is immediately disconnected from the input cell.  Also, I would prefer a style sheet edit solution so that I can easily apply the solution to new and existing notebooks.

Comment: You were supposed to change `StyleData["Output2", ...]` and any other occurence of `"Output2"` to `"DisplayFormula"`, not the `"Output"`. Also notice that is is a stylesheet solution, `StyleDefinitions -> Notebook[...]` is a stylesheet. You can create that Notebook separately and save it somewhere to reuse or whatever you need.

Comment: @Kuba Yes. That is the ticket. This can be marked as a duplicate.